# Why do I get the feeling that my colleagues do not understand some aspects of the project that we code, despite being experienced ones

Tags: software-development

Sometimes I feel like that my colleagues or my manager, cannot get a hard feeling about some technical aspects of the current project that I work.

My colleagues mostly are experienced developers (whereas I am the developer with most years in this company) and I am the youngest of them. But sometimes I feel frustrated (and not actively expressed towards them) because I understand that they say nonsense as if the do not have a good understanding about coding.

For example I need access to a Linux server. Therefore, I give my public ssh key and I get yelled at for doing so.

How I can combat the frustration that I am feeling? Is that because of my personal ego or because I can understand better computers that human people?

---

What I need to explain using the `cannot get a hard feeling` is that cannot predict some simple stuff like for giving an access to an X/Y system I need the Z stuff.

Or I need to do some stuff yesterday and a whole new technology is presented to me instead of improving adding to an existing one.

Comment: "A hard feeling" is not a typical English idiom, at least in this context. Could you try and rephrase / explain what you are referring to here?

Comment: Did they really yell ? As in 'shout' ? Because that's out of line, whether you said something stupid or not.

Comment: As Marianne013 says the yelling is out of line, but I think we need more detail. What exactly did they say was wrong with giving your ssh key?

Comment: Nobody knows everything. It's hard to tell from the question how ignorant they are. For instance older engineers will probably not know every aspect of the hot new technology and they should be open to learning. But maybe they are really out of touch or ignorant. And then there are differences that are differences of opinion not of fact, e.g. "X technology is best for this" - you'll have to deal with those sort of differences all the time, because often you have to use suboptimal technology for one reason or another.

Comment: @StuartF I mean simple stuff such as not writing a Prepared SQL statement or not providing some documentation for the code they wrote. Not X best for this or Y best of this mentality. I mean how hard it NOT to hardcode a Url for an 3rd pary API upon a brand new system?

Comment: It is unclear what "cannot get a hard feeling" is supposed to mean. Is this perhaps translated incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

There are really only two answers to what you're saying - either you aren't fully understanding them and you need to work on your interpersonal skills, or your team and/or company sucks. Since you can't really do anything about the second except leave, it's best to assume it's a communication or ego problem on your part and do your best to improve and work with your team to understand them. If, in the end, it is your company and you wind up leaving, it's still a useful and valuable experience.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps their experience lets them see solutions you don't, or lets them see why those solutions are better?

Ask them.

Comment: Also I notice stuff such as I need a Jira ticket for that or sth like that and I do not get them. In the end I end up doing the nessesary tickets for myself.

Comment: It may be that they simply disagree with you on the priority of those tickets. If you have time between assigned tasks, go for it, in priority order. Initiative is good.

Comment: And in fact, if you're using Jira, proper practice _is_ that every task gets entered, assigned a severity/priority/time estimate, and you pick tasks off that, recording when they're assigned to you and when they're completed. Among other things, this keeps everyone focused on what most matters, and gives you feedback for improving your estimating skills.